# What does it mean when a property is highlighted in green?

Tags: properties

I'm trying to edit a template I downloaded for a personal project.  I have specific axis values from a previous version of the template that I wish to add to the updated version.  However when I do, and I move the timeline cursor to review it, the properties revert back to their previous values.  The fields that I'm trying to change are highlighted in green for a reason I'm not entirely sure about, but presumably it's connected to the trouble I'm having.

So my question is twofold; what does it mean when properties are highlighted in green and, if the two are not connected, is there any way I can correct the issue?

I'm running Blender version 2.62 on a Windows 8.1 64-bit operating system.  I've attached a couple photos in case they will be helpful.

[image: original template version]

[image: new template version]

Answer (score 11):

Green means a property has a keyframe applied, but not on the current frame. (yellow means the key is on the current frame). Your changes aren't sticking because it's reverting to the keyed values. You can set a new key if you'd like by right-clicking the field and hitting "insert keyframe", adjust the key values in the graph editor, or just clear them all by right-clicking the prop and hitting "clear keyframes"

Also, for the sake of completeness, a purple property is one that has a [driver](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/basics/drivers.html) set.

Comment: Just to be clear, a *[Keying set](http://blender.org/manual/animation/basics/keying_sets.html)* is distinct from a *Keyframe*, which is the term I think you want. On second reading I think I see that I just mis-read your answer, but for clarity you might want to re-word it so "keyframe" and "set" aren't right next to each other ;)