# Can't change positioning of item after keyframe

Tags: video, keyframes, properties

So I'm video editting and I keyframe a translation of an image. The property value turns yellow, showing that that frame is the keyframe for that certain value. However, when I go to any other frame and try to keyframe to a different value, the property value is green and I am not able to change the value at all. Whenever I attempt to change it, the value reverts back to the keyframed value. I don't know what to do or how to revert this issue. This happened randomly. Deleted and re adding the image doesn't help and this is happening to anything that I try to keyframe.

I've tried to insert new keyframes and clear the keyframes, but those aren't working... the problem keeps on happening as soon as I add the keyframe...

The issue is similar to the one posted here, except there is no solution to the issue that has worked:

[What does it mean when a property is highlighted in green?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33875/what-does-it-mean-when-a-property-is-highlighted-in-green/33876#33876)

Comment: Please help, Idk why adding a keyframe suddenly locks the whole item in place... I can't animate anything in the project anymore...

Comment: Works fine for me in 2.77. There used to be a [bug involving keyframe in the VSE](https://developer.blender.org/T46552) which sounds similar.. What version of blender are you using?

Comment: Using 2.76b, but just updated to 2.77, the problem is still there

Comment: Hm.. I don't see the bug in the todo list anymore, but perhaps it hasn't been fixed yet. Do any of the workarounds stated [here](https://developer.blender.org/T32890) help (e.g. closing the preview)?

Comment: Could you provide a blend-File? Or write down the exact steps to reproduce the problem in a Factory-Default Startup file? Maybe your Interpolation type is set to Constant (hit T in the Graph Editor) and this confuses you...

Comment: @gandalf3 the [Todo](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=Dev:Source/Development/Todo/Tools&diff=prev&oldid=203807) from 2012-10-16 is still there: "Preview rendering resets animated properties when manually editing [T32890](https://developer.blender.org/T32890)". Though its description is somewhat confusing... But Sergej mentioned: **Workaround could be to close preview when animation or using auto-keyframing.**

Comment: Yeah, it's the same bug  [here](https://developer.blender.org/T32890)

Comment: @gandolf3 I've found a couple ways to work around though. Closing the preview works, but as soon as I open it back up again, it reverts back to the same issue. Also, I found out that I can make changes directly to the graph editor and the changes stay. Whichever the interpolation type is, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The keyframe fixes the property (in this case the position) not only for a certain frame but also influences the future ans past values of that property. By adding **only one** keyframe that value is fixed for all time on that property. (think of this as a piecewise defined function).

Your solution should be to add a new keyframe <kbd>i</kbd> on the frame you want to change the position. This should turn the property field yellow and you can set a new value for that frame. In the sidebar you can change the transition from one value to another over time.

No keyframe: the values are grey
[image]

keyframe on current frame (frame 0), values are yellow
[image]
frame 12 without keyframe, but a keyframe at frame 0 value is green (and cannot be permanently changed)
[image]
changed value and added new keyframe at frame 12. Values are yellow
[image]
frame 6 without keyframe, between frame 0 and 12, value is green and interpolated between these frames
[image]

Tldr: to have multiple values over time for one property you need multiple keyframes.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot add additional keyframes after adding the first keyframe. After I add the first keyframe, all other values of the image become green colored and whenever I try to change the value and keyframe it, the values just revert back to the originally keyframed value. So to summarize, I can keyframe an image once, but then it won't allow me to change any of the values to keyframe additional times. The value bar turns green. Usually, the value bar stays gray.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can pinpoint what process does not work

Comment: If it matters, I'm actually using video editing for an image transformation. The thing is, when I try to change the value, like changing x: 0.00 to x:1.00, the value reverts itself back to x:0.00 immediately after i take my mouse off of the value. I can't add a second keyframe unless it is the exact keyframe of the first value, and even then, I can't change the values at all. The values revert themselves back to the original keyframed values. Maybe would sending the file over help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I use the "Image offset" property in the "strip input subpannel". I keyframe x: 0 at frame 0, I move to frame 10, the value is 0 and has a green background, i type in another value (e.g. x: 10). The value stays unless I press "left","right" or something else to move to another frame (then it reverts to the first value). Above the changed value I press "i" to insert a new keyframe. No I have a keyframe at frame 0 with x:0 and at frame 10 with x: 10. Which of these steps does not work for you?

Comment: when I type in the other value. Like when I type in x:10 , the value immediately reverts back to x:0

Comment: Either I am missing something or this is a bug in the blenderversion you are using.

Comment: I'm using the latest version... It probably is a bug, but I have no idea what caused it.